# PowerShell output contents of hash to file

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have code to output a sorted hashtable to the screen:

```
$h.getenumerator() | sort value -descending
```

It looks like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
10.10.10.10 69566308           151
10.10.10.11 69566308           143
10.10.10.12 69566308           112
10.10.10.13 69566308            99
10.10.10.14 69566308            71
10.10.10.15 69566308            70
```

But I would like to output this to a file instead.

When I try to output to a file with

```
$h.getenumerator() | sort value -descending | out-string | Add-Content D:\Script\iis_stats.log
```

or

```
$h.getenumerator() | sort value -descending | Add-Content D:\Script\iis_stats.log
```

All I get is "System.Collections.DictionaryEntry" in `D:\Script\iis_stats.log`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: How do you want to format the output?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do the contents of your hashtable look like? Where does the data come from? What should the output look like?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ok I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it in the same format it displays on the screen (folded at the pipes for readability):

```
$h.getenumerator() | 
  Sort-Object value -descending | 
  Format-Table | 
  Out-String | 
  Add-Content D:\Script\iis_stats.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You would get similar output on your screen if you did something like this as well:

```
$h.GetEnumerator() | sort value -Descending | ForEach-Object{
    $_.GetType().FullName
}
```

For every entry you would see `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` since it does not have a proper string equivalent.

Then you should just do what mjolinor suggests. PowerShell automatically appends the `| Out-Default` command to the console so that it displays in a way that is visually pleasing. When you send the output to `Add-Content` that prettification cannot occur.